# How do I make terrain flatten under gameobject in Unity?

Tags: unity

In my game, you can build buildings. They are placed on the terrain. The problem is that my terrain is not flat, which means that when building a building, half of this building may hang in the air (see the example in image 1).

How do I make my terrain adapt to the constructed buildings (example in image 2)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Presumably you considered calling [TerrainData.GetHeights](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.GetHeights.html) to get an array of height values, adjusting the values in a region around your foundation, then calling [TerrainData.SetHeights](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeights.html) to apply your modifications back to the terrain? Did you run into any specific difficulty along the way that we can help with?

Comment: If you want to flatten the terrain, DMGregory's suggestion is correct. Other possible solutions you sometimes see in games are putting a concrete foundation under the building that extends fully into the terrain, or just not letting the player build where the terrain is very uneven (though the latter can be frustrating for players).